# Table Row's OnClick Event is Propagated to all Contained Elements?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, dom-events, dhtml

I've run into some interesting code in our legacy application running under Internet Explorer. Consider the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectRow()
  {
    var src = window.event.srcElement; // Array of OPTION?!
    var rowIndex = src.rowIndex; // Undefined for an OPTION element
    highlightRow(rowIndex);
  }
</script>
<table>
  <tr onclick="selectRow();">
    <td>
      <select id="foo">
        <option value="baz">baz</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, here's where I'm stumped. When the user selects an item from the SELECT element, the ONCLICK event is firing, and the following are true:

- `this` evaluates to `Window`
- `Window.event.srcElement` evaluates to an array of 'OPTION' elements
- There doesn't seem to be a way to get to the parent element of the options from within the event handler.

I need to be able to get the index of the table row that was clicked. (As you can see from the sample above, the legacy code incorrectly assumes that `this.rowIndex` evaluates to the table's current row index.)

I'm assuming that the culprit here is *event bubbling*.

I'm open to suggestions for correcting this problem in the most correct manner. It occurs to me that it could be the way the event is bound on the row, but I kind of doubt it (since the event would still bubble).

(FWIW, I have not tried this under any other browsers, since our company only supports IE. Please don't shoot the messenger.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing some additional complexity in your sample?  Because why not just:

```
<tr onclick="highlightRow(this.rowIndex);">
```

if that's really all you need to do with it.